# Running a process on MQTT message

Tags: bash, unix, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I would like to start a task (e.g. play audio file) on my RP when a receiving an MQTT packet.
What is the best way to approach it? I'm thinking either writing a c++ script or python. I'm not very sharp in Linux shell, and it could be that there is an even simpler way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it the same sound for each message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mosquitto_sub` to play a sound file (considering you have the sound file somewhere):

```
while read msg;
do
   aplay $msg;
done < <(mosquitto_sub -t topic -q 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer does not work on `ash` (the default shell on Busybox, as used on the Onion Omega for example). For an `ash` compatible solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

mosquitto_sub -R -h your.mqtt.host -t topic | while read RAW_DATA
do
  echo "Got msg" # replace with your task of choice
done
```

The `-R` flag prevents "stale" messages from being processed.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with [Node-RED](http://nodered.org/), it has a MQTT input node that will listen to a given topic (or wildcard topic) and an exec node that will run an arbitrary command, in this case something like *mpg123* or *aplay*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using Don Libes' expect:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

spawn mosquitto_sub -t mytop

while 1 {
    expect {
                "hello" {
                        puts "got hello"
                }
                "world" {
                        exec sh -c "touch world"
                }
                "bye" {
                        break
                }
    }
}
```